# Баги в работе слайдера при переключении кнопками

Tags: javascript, css, css3, анимация

По условию слайдер должен быть зациклен, а также переключаться по нажатию на кнопки. По отдельности работает все на ура, а вместе - ломается. 
Ситуация такая... Когда слайдер только начинает работу и появляется первый слайд, переключение по кнопкам срабатывает. Но как только выполняется часть анимации и первый сменяется вторым слайдом, это перестает работать. Точнее - если стоит второй слайд, то при нажатии на первую кнопку должен включиться первый, но она не работает... а начинает работать, только если перед этим нажать на вторую кнопку. Аналогично и для другого слайда...

```js
        var toggle1 = document.querySelector(".slide-1");
        var toggle2 = document.querySelector(".slide-2");
        var slide1 = document.querySelector(".first");
        var slide2 = document.querySelector(".second");


        toggle1.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
          //        event.preventDefault();
          //            slide2.classList.add("display-slide-1");
          //            slide1.classList.add("display-slide-2");
          //            slide2.classList.remove("display-slide-2");
          //            slide1.classList.remove("display-slide-1");

          //            slide2.classList.add("display-2");
          //            slide1.classList.add("display-1");


          slide2.classList.add("display-slide-2");
          slide1.classList.add("display-slide-1");

          //            slide2.classList.remove("display-slide-1");
          //            slide1.classList.remove("display-slide-2");
          //            
          //            slide2.classList.remove("display-2");
          //            slide1.classList.remove("display-1");
        });

        toggle2.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
          //        event.preventDefault();
          //            slide2.classList.add("display-slide-2");
          //            slide1.classList.add("display-slide-1");
          //            slide2.classList.remove("display-slide-1");
          //            slide1.classList.remove("display-slide-2");

          //            slide2.classList.add("display-1");
          //            slide1.classList.add("display-2");

          slide2.classList.add("display-slide-1");
          slide1.classList.add("display-slide-2");

          //            slide2.classList.remove("display-slide-2");
          //            slide1.classList.remove("display-slide-1");

          //            slide2.classList.remove("display-1");
          //            slide1.classList.remove("display-2");
        });
```

```css
.promo .slider-promo {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 620px;
  height: 265px;
  background-color: #f2f6f8;
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "CuprumRegular";
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider-promo .slide-item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(../img/promo-slide-1.jpg) no-repeat top left;
}
.slider-promo .second {
  /* display: none;*/
  background: url(../img/promo-slide-2.jpg) no-repeat top left;
}
.slider-promo .toggle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  bottom: 35px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -40px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 11px;
}
.slider-promo .label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
@keyframes first-animation {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
  }
  40% {
    left: 0;
  }
  50% {
    left: -620px;
  }
  51% {
    left: -620px;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  52% {
    left: 620px;
  }
  90% {
    left: 620px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}
@keyframes second-animation {
  0% {
    left: -620px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
  }
  1% {
    left: 620px;
  }
  40% {
    left: 620px;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  50% {
    left: 0;
  }
  90% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: -620px;
  }
}
.display-slide-1 {
  animation: first-animation 12s linear infinite;
}
.display-slide-2 {
  animation: second-animation 12s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-promo">
  <div class="slide-item first display-slide-1">
    <div class="name">
      <h3>перфораторы</h3>
      <span>Настоящие мужские игрушки</span>
    </div>
    <a href="" class="btn">открыть каталог</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-item second display-slide-2">
    <div class="name">
      <h3>дрели</h3>
      <span>Соседям на радость</span>
    </div>
    <a href="" class="btn">открыть каталог</a>
  </div>

  <div class="toggle">
    <div class="label slide-1"></div>
    <div class="label slide-2"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно сначала сделать

```
slide2.classList.remove('display-slide-1');
```

перед

```
slide2.classList.add("display-slide-2");
```

И также для каждого слайда и каждого события. Иначе у вас у слайдов стоят сразу display-slide-1 и display-slide-2.  Можете посмотреть, все работает https://jsfiddle.net/w4jbjyhp/

Comment: я пробовал так делать... Если посмотрите - я специально оставил закоментированные строки того, что пробовал... Пробовал имитировать нажатие второй кнопки - добавлять противоположные классы, потом их удалять и ставить необходимые... Но как-то без толку.    

И у вас все равно не работает( Попробуйте запустить код, подождать пока "перфораторы" сменяться "дрели" и нажать первую кнопку - она не работает

Comment: Так у вас одна кнопка и не должна работать. Одна кнопка всегда показывает активный слайд.

Comment: это да... но когда активный слайд - второй, а не работает первая кнопка. И срабатывает она, только если нажать сначала вторую, которая активная, а потом первую.